# CGpathaddrect in swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, core-graphics

i am converting to swift 3 and i am not sure what i did is correct.

old code:

```
CGPathAddRect(innerShadowPath, nil, bubblePath.boundingBoxOfPath.insetBy(dx: -30, dy: -30))
```

new code for swift 3:

```
innerShadowPath.addPath(bubblePath.boundingBoxOfPath.insetBy(dx: -30, dy: -30) as! CGPath)
```

Your help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CGPathAddRect` should be translated to `addRect`, not `addPath`.

```
innerShadowPath.addRect(bubblePath.boundingBoxOfPath.insetBy(dx: -30, dy: -30))
```